# How to animate this shape animation with rounded corners?

Tags: swift, uikit, uiviewanimation, uibezierpath, cgpath

Image for reference:

[image]

I need to animate from the leftmost shape to the rightmost shape. I have included intermediate frames as an example of what is so tricky about this (and necessary for the design): the corner radius effect where the two rectangles meet.

```
class TestRoundedCornerViews: UIView {
    
    let leftView = UIView()
    let middleView = UIView()
    let rightView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 16
        
        leftView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        leftView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        self.addSubview(self.leftView)
        
        middleView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        middleView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        self.addSubview(self.middleView)
        
        rightView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        rightView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        self.addSubview(self.rightView)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: Layout
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let leftSideWidth: CGFloat = 100
        
        let leftViewWidth: CGFloat = leftSideWidth / 2
        let middleViewWidth: CGFloat = leftViewWidth
        
        let rightViewWidth: CGFloat = 40
        
        leftView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: leftViewWidth,
            height: self.bounds.height
        )
        
        middleView.frame = CGRect(
            x: leftView.frame.maxX,
            y: 0,
            width: middleViewWidth,
            height: self.bounds.height
        )
        
        rightView.frame = CGRect(
            x: middleView.frame.maxX,
            y: 0,
            width: rightViewWidth,
            height: self.bounds.height
        )
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

}
```

Here's a visual of what that ends up like, using 3 views:

[image]

However it does not have that corner radius where the views meet, and I do not know how to animate that to the end position.

Comment: Why not `UIBezierPath`? You even tagged it.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I don’t know how to calculate the curves where the rectangles meet such that I could update it during an animation

Comment: @Miles - this is close... not sure if it will do? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTjfm.gif

Comment: @DonMag that's nice! It's not *quite* perfect but I imagine the math to make it look sticky the whole way is not worth the time. Is that done with only corner radius then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this animation by animating a `CAShapeLayer` path.

We start by adding 8 arcs to a `UIBezierPath` "startPath" (the connecting lines are automatically added):

[image]

Then we create an "endPath" moving the centers ... and we decreasing the radius to Zero where needed (arcs 2, 3, 6, 7):

[image]

We can then use `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")` with `.fromValue = startPath.cgPath` and `.toValue = endPath.cgPath` to "morph" from one shape to another.

You'll notice near the end of the animation that the corners being "straightened out" get a little "stepping" effect as their radius nears Zero... with some more math, and possibly chaining a few animations together, we could probably make that a little cleaner.

However, how noticeable it is depends on the speed of the animation and the overall size of the view, and may not be worth the effort.

Here's an example view subclass to do this:

```
class TestRoundedCornerViews: UIView {
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var startPath: UIBezierPath!
    var endPath: UIBezierPath!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        // if you want to watch the path border instead
        //shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        //shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        //shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
        
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }
    
    func doAnim() {
        
        let animation1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation1.fromValue = startPath.cgPath
        animation1.toValue = endPath.cgPath
        animation1.duration = 0.5
        animation1.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        animation1.fillMode = .both
        
        // un-comment next two lines to repeat and auto-revers
        //animation1.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        //animation1.autoreverses = true
        
        animation1.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        shapeLayer.add(animation1, forKey: animation1.keyPath)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let cr: CGFloat = 16
        
        let oneThirdWidth: CGFloat = bounds.width * 1.0 / 3.0
        let twoThirdWidth: CGFloat = oneThirdWidth * 2.0

        let oneThirdHeight: CGFloat = bounds.height * 1.0 / 3.0
        let twoThirdHeight: CGFloat = oneThirdHeight * 2.0

        // centers for startPath arcs (rounded corners)

        // top-left corner - will not change
        let c1: CGPoint = .init(x: cr, y: bounds.minY + cr)
        
        var c2: CGPoint = .init(x: twoThirdWidth - cr, y: bounds.minY + cr)
        var c3: CGPoint = .init(x: twoThirdWidth + cr, y: oneThirdHeight - cr)
        var c4: CGPoint = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: oneThirdHeight + cr)
        var c5: CGPoint = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: twoThirdHeight - cr)
        var c6: CGPoint = .init(x: twoThirdWidth + cr, y: twoThirdHeight + cr)
        var c7: CGPoint = .init(x: twoThirdWidth - cr, y: bounds.maxY - cr)
        
        // bottom-left corner - will not change
        let c8: CGPoint = .init(x: cr, y: bounds.maxY - cr)
        
        startPath = UIBezierPath()
        startPath.move(to: .init(x: 0.0, y: cr))
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c1, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c2, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c3, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: false)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c4, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c5, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c6, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: false)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c7, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        startPath.addArc(withCenter: c8, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: true)
        startPath.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = startPath.cgPath
        
        // centers for endPath arcs (rounded corners)
        c2 = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: bounds.minY)
        c3 = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: bounds.minY)
        c4 = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: cr)
        c5 = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: bounds.maxY - cr)
        c6 = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: bounds.maxY)
        c7 = .init(x: bounds.maxX - cr, y: bounds.maxY)
        
        endPath = UIBezierPath()
        endPath.move(to: .init(x: 0.0, y: cr))
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c1, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c2, radius: 0.0, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c3, radius: 0.0, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: false)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c4, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c5, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c6, radius: 0.0, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: false)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c7, radius: 0.0, startAngle: .pi * 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        endPath.addArc(withCenter: c8, radius: cr, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: true)
        endPath.close()

    }

}
```

and here's a simple view controller that shows the view (at `150 x 300` size), then animates on tap:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let testView = TestRoundedCornerViews()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0),
            
        ])
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testView.doAnim()
    }
}
```